# Gradle: how to exclude some tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle

My `src/test/` folder includes both unit and functional tests. The classpath of functional tests has the word `cucumber`, whereas the unit tests do not. So, how can I run the unit tests only?

Thank you very much.

**P.S.**: I know it is easy to use the "include" logic to select tests. For example, to only run the functional tests in my case, I can simply use this
`./gradlew test -Dtest.single=cucumber/**/`
However, I don't know how to exclude tests in a simple way.

BTW, I am using gradle 1.11.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[The documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) of the task explains it, with an example and everything:

```
apply plugin: 'java' // adds 'test' task

test {
  // ...

  // explicitly include or exclude tests
  include 'org/foo/**'
  exclude 'org/boo/**'

  // ...
}
```

Comment: --@JB Nizet: This will exclude some tests permanently. It is not flexible. What if I want to run all tests sometimes? Is it possible to create a task, say, `unitTest` that extends the `test` task but with some filtering?

Comment: Create another task called `cucumberTest`, of type `Test`, including only the cucumber tests, and a third task called `allTests` depending on `test` and on `cucumberTest`. You can then run `test` to run the unit tests, `cucumberTest` to run the cucumber tests, and `allTests` to run everything.

Comment: @user447607 what? I literally copied and pasted this example from the documentation. Have you at clicked the link?

Comment: OK I found it but it still isn't working for me. Naturally, I tried it first.

Comment: Scroll down to see JB Nizet's suggestion in code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211134/915441

Comment: org/foo/** are paths or packages?

Comment: paths. But the directory structure is supposed to match the package structure, so it doesn't change much.

Answer (score 38):

**Credit**: This answer is inspired by JB Nizet's answer. It is posted because it is more direct to my question.

To run the unit tests only, create a new task like this:

```
task unitTest( type: Test ) {
    exclude '**/cucumber/**'
}
```

This way we have:
run all tests: `./gradlew test`
run all unit tests: `./gradlew unitTest`
run all functional tests: `./gradlew test -Dtest.single=cucumber/**/`

Comment: If you are running tests with ./gradle build, I think you need to add the -x test on ./gradlew unitTest to avoid running both test and unitTest when doing a build as well.

Answer (score 15):

You can exclude this based on the external system properties.

```
-Dtest.profile=integration
```

and in build.gradle

```
test {
    if (System.properties['test.profile'] != 'integration') {
    exclude '**/*integrationTests*'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also define a custom flag in your `build.gradle`:

```
test {
    if (project.hasProperty('excludeTests')) {
        exclude project.property('excludeTests')
    }
}
```

Then in the command-line:

```
gradle test -PexcludeTests=com.test.TestToExclude
```

Comment: reference Mathijs de Groot: https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/10/run-one-or-exclude-one-test-with-gradle/

Answer (score 0):

With Gradle + Kotlin in your `build.gradle.kts`

```
tasks.test {
    if (System.getProperty("test.profile") != "integration") {
        exclude("**/*IntegrationTest*")
    }
}


gradle test -Dtest.profile=integration
```