# Spring Boot scans test folder on start-up

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle

I have a Spring Boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MySystem extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySystem.class, args);
    }
}
```

The project layout is like this:

```
MyApp/
    src/main/java
    src/test/java
    src/integration-test/java
```

In `src/integration-test/java` I have a Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
static class BootstrapIntegrationTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I start my Spring Boot app the `src/integration-test/java` folder will also be scanned and the `BootstrapIntegrationTestConfig` is loaded.

How can I prevent my Spring Boot app from scanning the `src/integration-test/java`?

I'm working with Eclipse and Gradle and I already tried to exclude `test` and `integration-test` from bin, but it didn't work:

```
import org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.SourceFolder
eclipse.classpath.file {
    beforeMerged { cp -> 
        cp.entries.clear()
    }
    whenMerged { cp ->
        cp.entries.findAll { it instanceof SourceFolder && it.path.startsWith("src/integration-test/") }*.output = "integration-test-bin"
        cp.entries.findAll { it instanceof SourceFolder && it.path.startsWith("src/test/") }*.output = "test-bin"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, how you assemble your application with Gradle? It's easier to fix the build process that is including the test configuration than trying to configure Spring. Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209181/gradle-how-to-exclude-some-tests ?

Comment: `EnableAutoConfiguration` has also `exclude` field. But it all seems strange a bit. Could you please move `integration-test` to `test`? You can also try to exclude `integration-test` on gradle level.