# How do I separate gradle unit tests from integration tests in the same source set?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

The problem is that we are an IntelliJ shop and [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151925) has been a thorn in our sides. It basically means that everything has to be in `./test/` in order to work. `./it/` isn't acceptable because IntelliJ picks it up as the wrong kind of source every time you try to do anything. So.... how do I separate integration tests from unit tests so that they can be run separately in Gradle if they are in the same source set? Anyone have an example?

We use the `*Test*.java` and `*ITCase*.java` naming conventions, if that helps. Anothing thing we were thinking of is some kind of use of JUnit's [@Category](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/categories) annotation.

P.S. Please vote for [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151925). It will be a thorn in the side of any IntelliJ shop considering Gradle that has integration tests in a different directory from unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to IntelliJ configuration, but in `build.gradle`, if you have:

```
test {
    if (! project.hasProperty("ITCASE")) {
        exclude "**/*ITCase*"
    }
}
```

then the following command-line would include the integration tests:

```
gradle test -PITCASE=true
```

and the standard would exclude them:

```
gradle test
```

Comment: What about just having two named source sets for the same location only different excludes / includes like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209181/gradle-how-to-exclude-some-tests

Comment: It's even easier than that. Our concern isn't when things get complied since that is pretty fast and even parallelizes well. It's when and if the tests get run, so it's OK to compile them at the same time as unit tests. That being said, I didn't need an extra source set. All I needed was an extra "type: Test" task with the includes and excludes set as you might expect.  Follow that up with check.dependsOn and you're stylin.