# separating unit and integrations tests in gradle with groovy

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, groovy, integration-testing

I'm trying to follow https://selimober.com/gradle_unit_integration/

Using a slightly different file structure:

```
src/test/integration/groovy
src/test/unit/groovy
src/test/resources
```

Running "gradle integration" - the compile runs OK and class files appear in:

```
build/classes/integration
build/classes/main/
```

But the tests themselves are never run. I think I'm missing a section in dependencies or a linking of integration to running tests but can't figure out what I'm missing. Unless its that I have to change the file structure and have Test in the taskname like "integrationTest"

I've tried adding:

```
check.dependsOn integration
```

and

```
integrationCompile sourceSets.main.output
integrationCompile configurations.testCompile
integrationCompile sourceSets.test.output
integrationRuntime configurations.testRuntime
```

and

```
task integ(type: Test) {  
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integ.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integ.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But that either hasn't changed anything or given me errors like:

```
Could not find method integrationCompile() for arguments [main classes] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Thanks for any help.

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
   maven {
             url repository_url
             credentials {
                 username = artifactory_user
                 password = artifactory_password
             }
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0',
        'javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:1.0',
        'org.apache.directory:groovy-ldap:1.0',
        'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5',
        'weblogic:wlfullclient:10.3.6',
        'javax.jms:jms:1.1'
    )

    testCompile(
        'junit:junit:4.12',
        'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
    )
}

sourceSets {
    unit {
        groovy {
            srcDir file('src/test/unit/groovy')
            exclude '**/integration/**'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/test/resources')
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + configurations.testRuntime
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + configurations.testRuntime
    }

    integration {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src/test/integration/groovy'
            exclude '**/unit/**'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/test/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + configurations.testRuntime
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + configurations.testRuntime
        }
    }

configurations {
    unitCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    unitRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime

    integrationCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task unit(type: Test) {
    include '**/unit/**'
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.unit.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.unit.runtimeClasspath
}

task integration(type: Test) {
    include '**/integration/**'
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Comment: maybe try src/test/groovy/integration or src/integration/groovy/. maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182439/how-do-i-separate-gradle-unit-tests-from-integration-tests-in-the-same-source-se

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your includes in the tasks:

```
task unit(type: Test) {
    include '**/unit/**'
}

task integration(type: Test) {
    include '**/integration/**'
}
```

You don't need that, the folders are defined by the source sets. The includes cause the tests to be limited to classes whose package includes "unit" resp. "integration".

Delete that and your tests should run.

BTW you don't need these excludes neither:

```
sourceSets {
    unit {
        groovy {
            exclude '**/integration/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @BigMac in that case, would you consider accepting the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your dependencies after source sets and configurations. Worked for me.