# How to exclude some tasks in gradle test

Tags: gradle, groovy, geb

```
gradle test
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test
```

I have a Integration test which is actually running with Groovy.

Above shows my current 'gradle test' job but I would like to run Java Unit test only and separate Groovy Test.

How do I skip certain tasks? Or How do I separate tasks in gradle test?

Comment: have you looked into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209181/gradle-how-to-exclude-some-tests ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: how to exclude some tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209181/gradle-how-to-exclude-some-tests)